# Is anyone doing professional flash / flex / actionscript development on a linux platform? Please share setups if you are

Tags: linux, apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I've used axdt ( http://new.axdt.org/ ) with Eclipse. I've read about fdt on on linux ( http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/73648.aspx ). FDT is a commercial package that I wouldn't mind paying for if it officially supported linux. Right now I'm using vim with the command line tools, and I'm not really satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Flex development on Linux.  It's working great!  Check out a screencast I created that shows how to use IntelliJ IDEA for Flex development on Linux:
http://www.jamesward.com/2010/09/22/flex-development-on-linux-with-intellij-idea/

Comment: Awesome.  For future reference, the flex modules are included in the IDEA 10 "Ultimate" edition, not the community edition.  I downloaded the EAP version (Early Access Program) installer at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+EAP

Comment: Also: The licensing for the Ultimate edition of Version 9 (version 10 final isn't available as of this writing) is $249. (Unrelated bonus: Version 10 Ultimate also comes with Android modules built in as well).

Answer (score 1):

The IntelliJ licence cost has just been halved for personal use.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/index.jsp

I have used it on OS X, Windows 7 and Linux. 
It's excellent and is a true poly-language IDE.